# How to create new table environment

Tags: tables, macros, environments

I am working on a book that has many many such tables. Is there a way to create shortcut  for the code shown below. I want to make table caption a variable, because in the MWE shown below except `\caption` and cell data everything else is constant.

what I am trying to achieve is - I should be able to say `\starttable` ..... `\endtable`
copying this much code will give me the results I want but it will make it less like LaTeX

```
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htbp]
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.5\linewidth}%\centering
{\caption{Table name - 1}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.1}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}

\hline
Text-1  & Text-2 & Text-3 & Text-4 \\
 \hline
   &  &  &  \\
  &   &   &   \\
&   &   &   \\
\hline
\end{tabular}}

\end{minipage}
\hspace{0.5cm}
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.5\linewidth}
\centering
{\caption{Table Name - 2}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.1}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
Text-1  & Text-2 & Text-3 & Text-4 \\
 \hline
   &  &  &  \\
  &   &   &   \\
&   &   &   \\
\hline
\end{tabular}}

\end{minipage}
\end{table}
```

Comment: I'm assuming your request for `\mytable`...`\endmytable` refers to the `tabular` and not the `table`, right?

Comment: @Werner yes thats correct, i forgot there is a table environment as well in latex

Comment: Does this help [what-is-the-best-way-to-setup-this-statblock-as-a-macro/](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31468/what-is-the-best-way-to-setup-this-statblock-as-a-macro/)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I can understand you desire to simplify capturing of tabular material and to keep the mark-up clean.

Normally, what I do for complicated tables is firstly to simplify the *row* entries. In your case we will mark the table data as follows:

```
\starttable
 \R test|test|test|test\\
 \R test|test|test|test\\
 \R test|test|test|test\\
\stoptable
```

I find using an "|" is easier to the eye than an "&" and the marked up text looks more tidy.
The `\starttable` and `\stoptable` are just two macros to hold the head and end materials.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\def\starttable{%
  \begin{table}[!htbp]
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.1}
  \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
  \hline
  Text-1  & Text-2 & Text-3 & Text-4 \\
 \hline}
\def\stoptable{\hline\end{tabular}\end{table}}
\def\R #1|#2|#3|#4{ #1&#2&#3&#4}

 \starttable
 \R test|test|test|test\\
 \R test|test|test|test\\
 \R test|test|test|test\\
\stoptable
\starttable %badly marked up table rather use the "|"
   &  &  &  \\
  &   &   &   \\
&   &   &   \\
\stoptable
\end{document}
```

Captions and other styling information can be added by modifying the `\startmacro` to take a parameter.

```
\def\starttable#1{%
\begin{table}[!htbp]
\caption{#1}
...
```

I am not sure if you always have "double tables". In such a case I will rewrite the above in a different set of macros, such as `\starttwotables` and `\endtwotables`. Please note that LaTeX will not allow you to define a macro starting with an `\end` unless it is an environment.

**Edit for multi-tables**

You can add one or more tables with same syntax as above. Enclose in `\begin{table}...`, if you need them to float or leave it out for immediate placement.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\usepackage[figurename=Figure.,
                  justification=RaggedRight, 
                  labelfont={bf, footnotesize}, 
                  textfont={footnotesize},position=top]{caption}
\begin{document}
\listoftables
\def\starttable#1{%
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.1}%
  \minipage{0.45\textwidth}
      \captionof{table}{#1}
      \tabular{|c|c|c|c|}
      \hline
      Text-1  & Text-2 & Text-3 & Text-4 \\
      \hline
}
\def\stoptable{%
   \hline\endtabular
   \endminipage\hspace{10pt}}
\def\R #1|#2|#3|#4{ #1&#2&#3&#4}

\newpage
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\starttable{First table caption}
 \R test|test|test|test\\
 \R test|test|test|test\\
 \R test|test|test|test\\
\stoptable
%
\starttable{This is the second caption}
 \R test|test|test|test\\
 \R test|test|test|test\\
 \R test|test|test|test\\
\stoptable
\bigskip

\starttable{This is the caption}
 \R test|test|test|test\\
 \R test|test|test|test\\
 \R test|test|test|test\\
\stoptable
%
\starttable{This is the caption}
 \R test|test|test|test\\
 \R test|test|test|test\\
 \R test|test|test|test\\
\stoptable

\starttable{This is the caption}
 \R test|test|test|test\\
 \R test|test|test|test\\
 \R test|test|test|test\\
\stoptable
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Other approaches are also possible.

Comment: @Aku I am going out at the moment, will post an extension to the code in the morning for this.

Comment: Yes the book I am working on will always have two tables side by side all the time, no exception. your solution presents clean solution for table but how would I put them side by side as I have shown in MWE and also be able to show caption on top of the table

Comment: Thanks for your help, I really appreciate it. However a small request, can you post your two table answer separate from what you have already given.  Because your one table solution is worth keeping in the post as well. :)

Comment: @Aku Please see edit

Comment: Any reason why you use two commands `\starttable` and `\stoptable`, instead of defining an environment (`\begin{mytable}`...`\end{mytable}`) for that?

Comment: @JoachimBreitner No particular reason, saves little bit of typing.

Answer (score 6):

You can define your custom environment. The first two tables are from your MWE, the third is the result of:

```
\begin{MyTabular}{Table Name - 3}
\end{MyTabular}
```

Given the way environments work, the above can also be written as follows which is closer to what you desired:

```
\MyTabular{Table Name - 3}
\endMyTabular
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\newenvironment{MyTabular}[1]{% #1 = caption
    \begin{table}[!htbp]
    \centering
    \caption{#1}
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.1}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
        \hline
        Text-1  & Text-2 & Text-3 & Text-4 \\
        \hline
        &   &   &  \\
        &   &   &   \\
        &   &   &   \\
        \hline
}{%
    \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htbp]
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.5\linewidth}%\centering
{\caption{Table name - 1}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.1}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}

\hline
Text-1  & Text-2 & Text-3 & Text-4 \\
 \hline
   &   &   &  \\
   &   &   &  \\
   &   &   &  \\
\hline
\end{tabular}}

\end{minipage}
\hspace{0.5cm}
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.5\linewidth}
\centering
{\caption{Table Name - 2}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.1}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
Text-1  & Text-2 & Text-3 & Text-4 \\
 \hline
   &   &   &  \\
   &   &   &  \\
   &   &   &  \\
\hline
\end{tabular}}

\end{minipage}
\end{table}

\begin{MyTabular}{Table Name - 3}
\end{MyTabular}
\end{document}
```