# How to hide table# & Break cell text into two rows

Tags: tables, captions

I asked for a new table environment here. [How to create new table environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46431/how-to-create-new-table-environment). I took the solution provided by `Yiannis` I works great

I have two questions -

I do not know how to break the cell content into two lines, because of that two tables are overlapping on one another. In the image, I want to break the line at red slash. I tried `\newcommand{\nl}{newline}`

I did not realize at the time of asking that each page has 10 tables, so 100 page document will have 1000 tables. Is there any way to get rid of `table-xxx:` from caption and just leave the text that I want to add to the caption. 
[image]

I would really appreciate your help

Since I could not explain the issue to cmhughes I am adding the desired output image as well. [image]

Comment: Try adding `\cr` and see if that is the result you want. Otherwise, I'd put the content in a `\parbox` of a fixed width and let TeX break it for you automatically. This can be automated with [the `collcell` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/collcell).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could load the `caption` package with

```
\usepackage[labelformat=empty]{caption}
```

which gives

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[labelformat=empty]{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
   \centering
   \caption{Test caption}
   \begin{tabular}{ll}
      1&2\\
      3&4
   \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\usepackage[labelformat=empty]{caption}` worked great, I was putting in the wrong place, but  `\\` did not work.

Comment: @Aku I'm a little confused now :) Did it work?

Comment: Removing the caption worked great, but new line did not work with `\\` its messing up the table. I want to keep the table structure intact and just be able to put two rows in certain cells.

Comment: @Aku I'm afraid I don't understand- what do you mean the new line did not work with `\`?

Comment: as you can see in the attached image, first table the lines are too long for the table. I want  the text to break into new row at the shown redline. this text `| अतथाः अतनिषाथाम् |` shows up in one line, I want it to show in twolines under the same cell. buy adding \\ to break the line did not work. I don't know how else to explain :(

Comment: @Aku I think I understand now. The issue you're describing has nothing to do with the caption though, it has to do with the `columntype` that you're using. If you want to be able to put two rows in a cell, then you could use the `p{<length>}` columntype, or perhaps consider putting the content in a `parbox`