# TikZ – How to create nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes

Based on one of the example posted [How to create new table environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46431/how-to-create-new-table-environment), I modified to my needs,

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\usepackage[labelformat=empty]{caption}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shapes,shadows,arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{fit,shapes.geometric}
\newcounter{nodemarkers}
\newcommand\circletext[1]{%
    \tikz[overlay,remember picture] 
        \node (marker-\arabic{nodemarkers}-a) at (0,1.5ex) {};%
    #1%
    \tikz[overlay,remember picture]
        \node (marker-\arabic{nodemarkers}-b) at (0,0){};%
    \tikz[overlay,remember picture,inner sep=2pt]
        \node[draw,ellipse,fit=(marker-\arabic{nodemarkers}-a.center) (marker-\arabic{nodemarkers}-b.center)] {};%
    \stepcounter{nodemarkers}%
}
\newcommand{\nl}{\newline}

\newcounter{nodecount}
\newcommand\tabnode[1]{\addtocounter{nodecount}{1} \tikz \node (\arabic{nodecount}) {#1};}
\tikzstyle{every picture}+=[remember picture,baseline]
\tikzstyle{every node}+=[inner sep=0pt,anchor=base,
minimum width=1cm,align=center,text depth=0.5ex,outer sep=1pt]
\tikzstyle{every path}+=[thick, rounded corners]

\begin{document}
\def\starttable#1{%
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.1}%
  \minipage{0.45\textwidth}
      \captionof{table}{#1}
      \tabular{p{1cm}p{1cm}p{1cm}p{1cm}}
} 
\def\stoptable{%
\endtabular
   \endminipage\hspace{30pt}}
\def\R #1|#2|#3|#4{ #1&#2&#3&#4}

\newpage
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\starttable{}
 \R test \nl text1 \nl text2|test|test|test\\
 \R test|test|test|test\\
 \R test|test|test|test\\
\stoptable
%
\starttable{}
 \R \tabnode{test \nl text3 \nl text4}|test|test|test\\
 \R test|test|test|test\\
 \R test|test|test|test\\
\stoptable
\end{table}

\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay]
\draw [red] (1.west) -- (1.north west) -- (1.north east) -- (1.south east) -- (1.south west) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Without a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages it is difficult to know. But you could try adding `text width=<length>` options to the `nodes`.

Comment: I modified that code with what I tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I modified your code to show the problem (with text in red) and it produces:

[image]

After adding `text width=1.5cm`:

[image]

And changing `\newcommand{\nl}{\newline}` to `\newcommand{\nl}{\\}`:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\usepackage[labelformat=empty]{caption}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\nl}{\\}

\newcounter{nodecount}
\newcommand\tabnode[1]{\addtocounter{nodecount}{1} \tikz \node [red] (\arabic{nodecount}) {#1};}
\tikzstyle{every picture}+=[remember picture,baseline]
\tikzstyle{every node}+=[inner sep=0pt,anchor=base,
minimum width=1cm,align=center,text depth=0.5ex,outer sep=1pt, text width=1.5cm]
\tikzstyle{every path}+=[thick, rounded corners]

\begin{document}
\def\starttable#1{%
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.1}%
  \minipage{0.45\textwidth}
      \captionof{table}{#1}
      \tabular{p{1cm}p{1cm}p{1cm}p{1cm}}
} 
\def\stoptable{%
\endtabular
   \endminipage\hspace{30pt}}
\def\R #1|#2|#3|#4{ #1&#2&#3&#4}

\newpage
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\starttable{}
 \R \tabnode{test \nl text1 \nl text2}|test|test|test\\
% \R test|test|test|test\\
% \R test|test|test|test\\
\stoptable
%
%\starttable{}
% \R test \nl text3 \nl text4|test|test|test\\
% \R test|test|test|test\\
% \R test|test|test|test\\
%\stoptable
\end{table}

%\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay]
%\draw [green] (1.west) -- (1.north west) -- (1.north east) -- (1.south east) -- (1.south west) -- cycle;
%\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the `\nl` to `\\` in the `\tabnode` and it works fine.

```
\tabnode{test \\ text1 \\ text2}
```